# How to return the element of a list if it contains some specific value?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
testlist=[{'p:Name':'ABC','p:Age':'14'},
          {'Major':'Science','Job':'Scientist'}, 
          {'p:Name':'XYZ','p:Age':'15'}]
testlist=list(testlist)
print(type(testlist))

itemNo1=testlist[0]
itemNo2=testlist[1]
itemNo3=testlist[2]

newseparatedlist=[itemNo1,itemNo2,itemNo3]
print(newseparatedlist,type(newseparatedlist))
```

As you see I have a list containing 3 elements (in a dictionary style). I need to return each element contains some specific value. For example, I want to check if the element contains `p:Age` then the output should return its value which is `14` in first element and `15` in last element.

Comment: I don't understand how the code you posted relates to the question you seem to be asking. I see you have `testlist = [ ...`, but you haven't posted any code which attempts to extract elements that pass a certain criteria.

Comment: What have you tried? Checking for existence and retrieving the value of keys in a dict is more or less the most basic action with a dict... (`if 'p:Age' in d` and `value = d['p:Age']`)

Comment: You can simply do sth like: `if "p:Age" in itemNo1: ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like the following:

```
[dico["p:Age"] for dico in testlist if "p:Age" in dico.keys()]
```

outputs:

```
['14', '15']
```

If you want the whole items you can do:

```
[{"p:Age":dico["p:Age"]} for dico in testlist if "p:Age" in dico.keys()]
```

outputs:

```
[{"p:Age":'14'}, {"p:Age": '15'}]
```

Comment: `key in d` is enough. No need to call `.keys()`

Comment: Thank you it works.. Please How can I also return the whole element? I mean, instead of '14', '15' >>> ["p:Age":'14', "p:Age": '15']...
I tried with dico.items() but it doesnt work!